# JList - não atualiza quando inicio novamente sessão

Tags: java

```
private DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel<>();          //modelo da lista de ficheiros
private JList listaFicheiros = new JList<>(model);      

new1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String nomeFicheiroNovo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Qual o nome do novo ficheiro?");

            //Criar um ficheiro novo e escrever para dentro dele

            File ficheiroNovo = new File(diretoriaExecucao + "/" + nomeFicheiroNovo + ".txt");   //dentro e a diretoria que queremos gravar ficheiro (em execucao)

            //escrever para o ficheiro
            try {
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(ficheiroNovo); 
                printWriter.println("Escreveu ficheiro?");                          //O que queremos escrever no ficheiro.
                model.addElement(ficheiroNovo.getName());                           //adicionar ficheiro à lista para aparecer frame

                printWriter.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
```

O new1 é um botão para criar um ficheiro novo. Este excerto de código funciona, o problema é quando fecho a frame e volto a abrir ela não assume que tem la o ficheiro novo que criei. Como atualizo a frame?

Comment: Mas de acordo com o código acima, só será atualizado quando o botão for clicado. O que você quer é executar isso sem precisar clicar no botão?

Comment: Abro a frame tenho dois ficheiros na jlist mas depois quando adiciono o ficheiro com o nome novo ele aparece na lista, mas quando fecho o frame e o abro outra vez só me aparece os 2 ficheiros que já lá estavam

Comment: Pode adcionar um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel simularmos o problema?

Comment: Quando estivera no pc faço isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que podes fazer é ir ao diretório em que tens os ficheiros e ires buscar o ultimo ficheiro modificado que suponho ser o novo ficheiro.

```
private File getLatestFilefromDir(String dirPath){
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified()) {
            lastModifiedFile = files[i];
        }
    }
    return lastModifiedFile;
}
```

[Aqui fica um link para o que precisas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064694/how-do-i-find-the-last-modified-file-in-a-directory-in-java).

Obs.: não te esqueças que se queres carregar quando inicias a JFrame então este método tem que ser chamado assim que carregas a JFrame.

Comment: Este método tambem está correto! Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

A minha própria pergunta não continha erros, eu é que só aceitava ficheiros no programa que acabavam em ".rtf" e estava a criar um ".txt". 
Neste caso eu criei uma pasta dentro do projecto que se chama ficheiro, por isso é que entro nessa pasta na instancia "diretoriaexecucao".

Em caso de querer ficheiros ".txt" meter f.getName().endsWith(".rtf");

Deixo aqui a parte que adiciono ficheiros do pc à lista:

```
    private String diretoriaExecucao = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "ficheiro";


    File[] files = new File(diretoriaExecucao).listFiles(new FileFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            return f.getName().endsWith(".rtf");        //so aceita ficheiros acabados em .rtf
        }
    });

    for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){          //como nao e array percorremos o tamanho por inteiro do array
        model.addElement(files[i].getName());
    }
```